# The number of slots calculated with the formula is not matching when checked in monitoring of BQ

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to compare the number of slots derived from the formula with the number of slots being in use at that particular time.
The formula to calculate the number of slots is : select ROUND(SAFE_DIVIDE(total_slot_ms,
TIMESTAMP_DIFF(end_time, start_time, MILLISECOND)), 2) AS approximateSlotCount from `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT
This count is showing 215.93 slots at 4:37 am UTC and if I see the same slots in Monitoring Page of BigQuery,I can see only 15 slots consumed at 10.07 am IST.Also we are using Slot Reservation and not On-Demand

Expecting number of slots to be around 215 at 10.08 am IST.Although the number of slots at 10 am are 240.

Answer (score 0):

The Query you provided is to calculate the average slot usage at job level. While the BQ monitoring dashboard provides the slot usage at reservation level. You can modify the query to view the jobs that were created during the time range you want to check and view all the jobs created during that time range.

```
    SELECT ROUND(SAFE_DIVIDE(total_slot_ms, TIMESTAMP_DIFF(end_time, start_time, MILLISECOND)), 2) AS approximateSlotCount
  ,* FROM region-eu.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT
  where start_time between '2023-07-22 15:20:34.970000 UTC' and '2023-07-22 20:20:34.970000 UTC'
```